# How do I turn off fractional frames?

Tags: keyframes

I'm very surprised that the latest Blender version has essentially an infinite number of frames between each integer frame. I only want to work with integers, for obvious reasons. How do I turn that off? Why did that become a default feature? For example, when grabbing and moving a keyframe, it can be moved to frame 2.5000. So there's 4 significant figures of freedom in a keyframe now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change timeline to Dope Sheet:

[image]

Open snap menu and select Frame:

[image]

Change back to timeline:

[image]